# doors detection and navigation with point cloud datas

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to ask for some help regarding point cloud data and doors detection / navigation through them. The map is created using Gmapping and map server and can obtain parameters such a seed or closest distance to the wall. Try to figure out some algorithms for doors detection and write my own node. Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40457/doors-detection-and-navigation-with-point-cloud-datas/) by [DuranDuran71](https://answers.ros.org/users/2966/duranduran71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is this amazing recent paper published in ICRA 2013  which has given a great solution for your problem "Automated Doorway Detection for Assistive Shared-Control Wheelchairs" by Matthew Derry and Brenna Argall.

---

Originally posted by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) with karma: 311 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1